# How to customise the Camera screen frame?

Tags: iphone, camera, camera-overlay

I want to lauch camera with customised frame so that I should be able to show `UIsearchBar` in the same View and on touching the `UISearchBar` I need to close the camera, but the `UIsearchBar` should be visible. So I want to stop the camera to take the full iPhone screen as a frame.
So I want to know how to customise the Camera Screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options. The easiest one is to use the cameraOverlayView property of the UIImagePickerController. This allows you to display a view on top of the camera:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView

If you need something more elaborate you can use the AVFoundation framework. In short, it will allow you to display the camera stream anywhere you want in a view:
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2

Here is a simple tutorial on how to take a picture with AVFoundation: http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297